# Getting Error when add new field date in entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Actually I am using Liquibase with Spring Boot and I added `createAt` column in database. And change my Entity and add extra field like this private `LocalDate` `createdAt` in my existing entity.

I'm getting the following error whenever trying to post or get request:

> SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22 Unknown column
>   'restapient0_.created_at' in 'field list' Error performing load
>   command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
>   extract ResultSet

I can't find create_at column anywhere in database

Comment: If you can't find it, and if Hibernate can't find it, it's probably that it's not there. Which means you haven't created it. Which means your liquibase changelog is wrong, or that it hasn't run.

Comment: Its created by liquibase in my table createdAt(with this name) but when i send get and post request via postman its giving me error Unknown column 'restapient0_.created_at' in 'field list' Error, i added in my entity a new filed createdAt with LocalDate data type but its not working giving me error

Comment: So, you know what the problem is: the column must be named created_at, not createdAt. That's what the default JPA configuration used by Spring Boot uses as a naming convention.

Comment: thanks, let me try with this, but before i change default JPA configuration too , but it's did not work for me, Let me try again

Comment: Problems solved::when I added created_at column using liquibase it's working, the entity is giving me error. because JPA use default name convention and was not accepting my name convention in db like createdAt, that's why its gave me error, thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

You are telling that you added a column named `createAt` but you created a field like `private LocalDate createdAt` which is not matching.

One place `createAt` and other place `createdAt` ?

Looks like a typo..Isn't it?

Comment: No its with same name as in database createdAt, there is spelling mistake when i ask question here